# Why is react setState not working inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, setstate, use-effect

Hello I am trying to build a chat application using React and Socket.io. And there is a part where I emit a "joined" event from the server to the client to let the client know that he had successfully joined a room and also to send the chat history of the room. This is how the client handles the "joined" event:

```
useEffect(() => {
   socket.on('joined', (roomx) => { setCurrentRoom(roomx); setMessages(roomx.messages)});
}, [currentRoom]);
```

I passed a second argument ([currentRoom]) to useEffect because if I don't, "joined" will be called 4 or 5 times.

I tried console.logging in setCurrentRoom callback to see if setCurrentRoom is being called at all, like this:

```
setCurrentRoom(roomx, () => { console.log(currentRoom)};
```

However, nothing is being logged.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here? or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
setCurrentRoom(roomx, () => { console.log(currentRoom)};
```

`setCurrentRoom` hasn't the second argument as callback instead of `this.setState`. That's why nothing is being logged.

---

```
useEffect(() => {
   socket.on('joined', (roomx) => { setCurrentRoom(roomx); setMessages(roomx.messages)});
}, [currentRoom]);
```

You don't need `currentRoom` in second argument. `[currentRoom]` it means every time when currentRoom was changed - call first argument from useEffect. I suppose you want to call socket.on only once.

here is an example

```
useEffect(() => {
   socket.on('joined', (roomx) => {
     setCurrentRoom(roomx);
     setMessages(roomx.messages);
   });
}, []);
```

And if component will unmount you have to remove listener.

```
useEffect(() => {
   const listener = (roomx) => {
     setCurrentRoom(roomx);
     setMessages(roomx.messages);
   };

   socket.on('joined', listener);

   return () => {
     socket.off('joined', listener);
   };
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question though. How do I check currentRoom's value since if I just log it after setCurrentRoom it will just be undefined?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand your question.

Comment: @kyljmn You can log it directly in the component, you will see the updated value post a re-render